# How to test localization in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, localization, moss

I have created a feature with the description localized.

Now I want to be able to test this localization. At first I thought, let me just change the location of the computer in the control panel, but this seemed to have no effect.

So my question is - how can I test a location in SharePoint?

Another way to ask this question would be what is localization in MOSS based on?

Thanks in advance

Also just to clarify, I have localized the feature, and it is currently pulling from default(english) so that is all set, and I have created another Czech resource file. Not interested in how to implement localization, I need to know how to test it only....

Answer (score 0):

Localization is determined by the UI language. So create a site in a different language (i.e. you need to have a language pack installed).

Comment: I need MOSS Language packs installed?